# Using HTML entities like &ndash; or &mdash; with template literals

Tags: javascript, unicode, html-entities, template-literals

Having this template literal:

```
`HH:MM${myValue? '' : ', XXX'}${anotherValue} - `
```

I want to replace the hyphen at the end (`-`) with en dash (`–`) by using its code `&ndash;`.

I tried several methods but none of them worked. For example:

```
`HH:MM${myValue? '' : ', XXX'}${anotherValue} &ndash; `
```

and

```
`HH:MM${myValue? '' : ', XXX'}${anotherValue}  + '&ndash;'`
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: have you tried `HH:MM${myValue? '' : ', XXX'}${anotherValue} –`?

Comment: Some clarifying questions: Why can't you just replace the `-` with a `–`? Why are you using `&ndash;`? What do you mean is doesn't "work"?

Comment: I know that it works like that but I need to do it without using that method

Comment: You'll need to add more information about what you're trying to do and why that doesn't work.

Comment: @JamesKraus There could be many different reasons why someone needs to use an html entity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use html entities in a template literal. But you can use the unicode equivalent of the `&ndash;`:

```
`HH:MM${myValue? '' : ', XXX'}${anotherValue} \u2013 `
```

See here: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm